# Google App Engine - 404 but only for .js files

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a nuxt app deployed to GAE. My previous deploy happened about a month ago, the app was working as expected after that. I made some text changes recently, but after deploying saw that the app is not working as all the requests against .js files returned with 404.

My app.yml looks like the following:

```
runtime: nodejs14
instance_class: F2

handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    secure: always

  - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
    static_files: static/\1
    upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always

env_variables:
  HOST: '0.0.0.0'
  NODE_ENV: 'staging'
```

I've double checked in GAEs debugger that the .js files are there in the `.nuxt/dist/client`  folder. I have an additional file there `/.nuxt/dist/client/LICENSE`, and GAE returns that without any problem when triggering a request `<domain>/_nuxt/LICENSE`. So it's just the .js files GAE doesn't want to serve...

Does anyone any suggestion?

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I cannot see any error other than the fact of the 404 response. Here're the logs and how dev-tools looks like.
[image: dev-tools-sc]
[image: gce-logs-sc]

Comment: Can you provide the exact error in the application?

Also, do check the application logs to make sure what happens on GAE using this command `gcloud app logs tail`?

Comment: Thanks @DominicT, just edited my question and included the details you've asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using custom server with your Nuxtjs, my solution is removing these two handlers in `app.yaml`.

For some reason my deployment failed today and got it fixed.

```
handlers:
  # - url: /_nuxt
  #   static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
  #   secure: always

  # - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt))$
  #   static_files: static/\1
  #   upload: static/.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|txt)$
  #   secure: always

  - url: /.*
    script: auto
    secure: always
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhaimin-Taib! Not exactly sure why and how, but it works! Do you know how on earth GCE figures out that it's gonna find the resources in .nuxt/dist/client folder when the user requests them like /_nuxt/<file>?

Comment: @Joooe glad that it fixed yours too! If you’re using custom server with nuxtjs, the server itself is serving and routing /_nuxt/* path to the correct bundled js files, so having a separate handler of static files in app.yaml was kind of redundant.  And from the look of it, something happened that’s making the hashed nuxt bundled filename differs from those that’re supposed to be during runtime, this part I couldn’t figure out why.